# error while backing up oracle database using rman

Tags: rman

I have a RMAN backup of 11G Release 1; the backup is full backup mean it includes control file, datafiles and archivelogs. The database name is ORCL and OS is windows XP.

Now I want to restore this backup on new machine, the new machine is also windows XP and the directory structure is 100% same as on old machine.

What I do on new machine; I install the 11 G R1 and create database with name of ORCL and copy the rman backup folder on new machine in same directory as it was on old machine.

I got the problem (RMAN-03002) while recover the database.

Below the following steps.

```
C:\> sqlplus sys/kris@orcl as sysdba
Sql> shutdown immediate;
Sql> exit;
C:\> set oracle_sid = orcl
C:\> rman
RMAN> connect target orcl
RMAN> startup nomount;
RMAN> restore controlfile from autobackup;

Starting restore at 16-DEC-12
using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=152 device type=DISK

recovery area destination: D:\app\administrator\flash_recovery_area
database name (or database unique name) used for search: ORCL
channel ORA_DISK_1: AUTOBACKUP D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\AUT
OBACKUP\2012_12_12\O1_MF_S_801849930_8DJQHTTW_.BKP found in the recovery area
AUTOBACKUP search with format "%F" not attempted because DBID was not set
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring control file from AUTOBACKUP D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\
FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\AUTOBACKUP\2012_12_12\O1_MF_S_801849930_8DJQHTTW_.BKP
channel ORA_DISK_1: control file restore from AUTOBACKUP complete
output file name=D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\CONTROL01.CTL
output file name=D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\CONTROL02.CTL
output file name=D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\CONTROL03.CTL
Finished restore at 16-DEC-12

RMAN> alter database mount;

database mounted
released channel: ORA_DISK_1



RMAN> catalog recovery area;



Starting implicit crosscheck backup at 16-DEC-12
allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=152 device type=DISK
Crosschecked 5 objects
Finished implicit crosscheck backup at 16-DEC-12

Starting implicit crosscheck copy at 16-DEC-12
using channel ORA_DISK_1
Finished implicit crosscheck copy at 16-DEC-12

searching for all files in the recovery area
cataloging files...
cataloging done

List of Cataloged Files
=======================
File Name: D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\ARCHIVELOG\2012_12_12\O
1_MF_1_1450_8DK6YO0M_.ARC
File Name: D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\ARCHIVELOG\2012_12_13\O
1_MF_1_1451_8DLPSYDY_.ARC
File Name: D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\ARCHIVELOG\2012_12_13\O
1_MF_1_1452_8DLVBJZ7_.ARC
File Name: D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\ARCHIVELOG\2012_12_13\O
1_MF_1_1452_8DM0LM1L_.ARC
File Name: D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\ARCHIVELOG\2012_12_13\O
1_MF_1_1453_8DM0LM1L_.ARC
File Name: D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\ARCHIVELOG\2012_12_13\O
1_MF_1_1454_8DM0NQ8X_.ARC
File Name: D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\AUTOBACKUP\2012_12_12\O
1_MF_S_801849930_8DJQHTTW_.BKP

searching for all files in the recovery area

List of Files Unknown to the Database
=====================================
File Name: D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\ARCHIVELOG\2012_12_13\O
1_MF_1_1453_8DLXCJOB_.ARC

Do you really want to catalog the above files (enter YES or NO)? Y
cataloging files...
no files cataloged

List of Files Which Where Not Cataloged
=======================================
File Name: D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\ARCHIVELOG\2012_12_13\O
1_MF_1_1453_8DLXCJOB_.ARC
  RMAN-07517: Reason: The file header is corrupted



RMAN> list backup;



List of Backup Sets
===================


BS Key  Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time
------- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
512     245.35M    DISK        00:00:39     12-DEC-12
        BP Key: 512   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: NO  Tag: TAG20121212T160059

        Piece Name: D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\BACKUPSET\2012
_12_12\O1_MF_ANNNN_TAG20121212T160059_8DJQ7OF3_.BKP

  List of Archived Logs in backup set 512
  Thrd Seq     Low SCN    Low Time  Next SCN   Next Time
  ---- ------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------
  1    1440    487654314  09-DEC-12 487695982  10-DEC-12
  1    1441    487695982  10-DEC-12 487719639  10-DEC-12
  1    1442    487719639  10-DEC-12 487741536  10-DEC-12
  1    1443    487741536  10-DEC-12 487741634  10-DEC-12
  1    1444    487741634  10-DEC-12 487771824  10-DEC-12
  1    1445    487771824  10-DEC-12 487803737  12-DEC-12
  1    1446    487803737  12-DEC-12 487810247  12-DEC-12
  1    1447    487810247  12-DEC-12 487819910  12-DEC-12
  1    1448    487819910  12-DEC-12 487837944  12-DEC-12

BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time
------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
513     Full    1.94G      DISK        00:03:18     12-DEC-12
        BP Key: 513   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: NO  Tag: TAG20121212T160150

        Piece Name: D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\BACKUPSET\2012
_12_12\O1_MF_NNNDF_TAG20121212T160150_8DJQ92L5_.BKP
  List of Datafiles in backup set 513
  File LV Type Ckp SCN    Ckp Time  Name
  ---- -- ---- ---------- --------- ----
  1       Full 487837993  12-DEC-12 D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\SYSTEM01.D
BF
  2       Full 487837993  12-DEC-12 D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\SYSAUX01.D
BF
  3       Full 487837993  12-DEC-12 D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\UNDOTBS01.
DBF
  4       Full 487837993  12-DEC-12 D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\USERS01.DB
F
  5       Full 487837993  12-DEC-12 D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\EXAMPLE01.
DBF
  6       Full 487837993  12-DEC-12 D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\HMS_SMILE.
DBF
  7       Full 487837993  12-DEC-12 D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\HMS_GENERA
L.DBF
  8       Full 487837993  12-DEC-12 D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\HMS_EMR.DB
F
  9       Full 487837993  12-DEC-12 D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\HMS_DIAGNO
STICS.DBF
  10      Full 487837993  12-DEC-12 D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\HMS_PHARMA
CY.DBF
  11      Full 487837993  12-DEC-12 D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\HMS_PATIEN
T.DBF
  12      Full 487837993  12-DEC-12 D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\HMS_ACCOUN
T.DBF
  13      Full 487837993  12-DEC-12 D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\HMS_INVENT
ORY.DBF
  14      Full 487837993  12-DEC-12 D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\HMS_HR.DBF

  15      Full 487837993  12-DEC-12 D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\HMS_DUMMY.
DBF
  16      Full 487837993  12-DEC-12 D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\HMS_AUDIT.
DBF
  17      Full 487837993  12-DEC-12 D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\HMS_FACILI
TIES.DBF
  19      Full 487837993  12-DEC-12 D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\HMS_COMMON
.DBF

BS Key  Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time
------- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
514     222.00K    DISK        00:00:06     12-DEC-12
        BP Key: 514   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: NO  Tag: TAG20121212T160520

        Piece Name: D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\BACKUPSET\2012
_12_12\O1_MF_ANNNN_TAG20121212T160520_8DJQHGS1_.BKP

  List of Archived Logs in backup set 514
  Thrd Seq     Low SCN    Low Time  Next SCN   Next Time
  ---- ------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------
  1    1449    487837944  12-DEC-12 487838190  12-DEC-12

BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time
------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
515     Full    12.17M     DISK        00:00:00     12-DEC-12
        BP Key: 515   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: NO  Tag: TAG20121212T160530

        Piece Name: D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\AUTOBACKUP\201
2_12_12\O1_MF_S_801849930_8DJQHTTW_.BKP
  SPFILE Included: Modification time: 12-DEC-12
  SPFILE db_unique_name: ORCL
  Control File Included: Ckp SCN: 487838210    Ckp time: 12-DEC-12




RMAN> run {
              Set until 1450   …. [sequence number taking from list backup command]
              Restore database;
              Recover database;
          }


executing command: SET until clause

Starting restore at 16-DEC-12
using channel ORA_DISK_1

channel ORA_DISK_1: starting datafile backup set restore
channel ORA_DISK_1: specifying datafile(s) to restore from backup set
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring datafile 00001 to D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORC
L\SYSTEM01.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring datafile 00002 to D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORC
L\SYSAUX01.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring datafile 00003 to D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORC
L\UNDOTBS01.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring datafile 00004 to D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORC
L\USERS01.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring datafile 00005 to D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORC
L\EXAMPLE01.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring datafile 00006 to D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORC
L\HMS_SMILE.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring datafile 00007 to D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORC
L\HMS_GENERAL.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring datafile 00008 to D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORC
L\HMS_EMR.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring datafile 00009 to D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORC
L\HMS_DIAGNOSTICS.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring datafile 00010 to D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORC
L\HMS_PHARMACY.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring datafile 00011 to D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORC
L\HMS_PATIENT.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring datafile 00012 to D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORC
L\HMS_ACCOUNT.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring datafile 00013 to D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORC
L\HMS_INVENTORY.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring datafile 00014 to D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORC
L\HMS_HR.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring datafile 00015 to D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORC
L\HMS_DUMMY.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring datafile 00016 to D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORC
L\HMS_AUDIT.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring datafile 00017 to D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORC
L\HMS_FACILITIES.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring datafile 00019 to D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORC
L\HMS_COMMON.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: reading from backup piece D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\FLASH_RECOVER
Y_AREA\ORCL\BACKUPSET\2012_12_12\O1_MF_NNNDF_TAG20121212T160150_8DJQ92L5_.BKP
channel ORA_DISK_1: piece handle=D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\B
ACKUPSET\2012_12_12\O1_MF_NNNDF_TAG20121212T160150_8DJQ92L5_.BKP tag=TAG20121212
T160150
channel ORA_DISK_1: restored backup piece 1
channel ORA_DISK_1: restore complete, elapsed time: 00:04:55
Finished restore at 16-DEC-12

Starting recover at 16-DEC-12
using channel ORA_DISK_1
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of recover command at 12/16/2012 14:13:39
ORA-19698: D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO01.LOG is from different databa
se: id=1329913169, db_name=ORCL
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know it's a bit too late, but it looks like that redolog (as well as its probably neighbours from the same directory) just left stalled from your previous experiments from other database there.